# AlphaNumeric Validation for PhoneNumber (International) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement that alphanumeric should not be allow for Phone Number validation, here we have to allow only +,() and 0-9 only . here i gave only for alphabets, but when i am giving alphanumeric that one is taken. the following is my code shown. can any one suggest me how to write.

```
$("#PhoneNumber").focusout(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    var Phone = $("#PhoneNumber").val()
    if (Phone != "") {
        var re = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
        var result = re.test(Phone);
        console.log(result);
        if (!result) {
            $("#msgPhone").text('Enter Numeric Numbers only');
        }
        else {
            $("#msgPhone").text("Go ahead !");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you like to share one example against which you want to validate?

Comment: should be allow +, and 0-9 numbers.

Comment: That's a long regex that seems to do a lot more than match a few characters

Comment: @sandeeps like +918000012345 ?... or standardized +91-800-001-2345?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar i want standardized only. i am sorry to say this as a EndUser how they are entering phone number. we don't know that, if it is possible i want both validations.

Comment: @sandeeps You may want to try this.. /^(\+\d{2})[-]?(\d{3})[-]?(\d{3})[-]?(\d{4})$/